# Android Studio 4.2 - Keyboard Shortcut Problem

Tags: android-studio

Today I updated to Android Studio version 4.2. I noticed that the "cmd + shift + r" and "cmd + shift + f" shortcut is not working. Is there a regulation for the MacOs operating system?

MacOs version : MacOS Catalina

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Android Studio - Preferences - Keymap - Keymap List - MacOs selected and fixed.
Intellij idea classic did not work when selected.

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed it here also. cmd + shift + f was changed to ctrl + shift + f, and so does ctrl + shift + r.

I could not find yet which is the replacement for option + up key.